# C# XML - Set Inner Text from a child based in attribute value

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to get directly the child from its attribute value, is it possible straigh foward?

```
        foreach (XmlNode ext_cell_HO in ext_cells_HO)
        {
            new_node = xml_doc.ImportNode(ext_cell_HO.CloneNode(true), true);
            new_node["p[@name='AdjiRNCid']"].InnerText = rnc_id.ToString();
            xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("/raml/cmData").AppendChild(new_node);

        }
```

new_node["p[@name='AdjiRNCid']"].InnerText = rnc_id.ToString();

this is the line not working.
If I put 
new_node["p"].InnerText = rnc_id.ToString();
it is ok but not the one I want because it goes to the first child.
XML example:

```
<managedObject class="classadj" id="232">
  <p name="AdjiMCC">208</p>
  <p name="AdjiMNC">01</p>
  <p name="AdjiCI">17750</p>
  <p name="AdjiLAC">1800</p>
  <p name="AdjiRAC">1</p>
  <p name="AdjiRNCid">158</p>
</managedObject>
```

Help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
new_node.SelectSingleNode("p[@name='AdjiRNCid']")
```

Comment: Exact! omg, so easy... :/ I thought the select single node did not start from the node that calls it. I thought it was needed always the full xpath. Thank you a lot Henrik

Comment: @JoãoPaulo: my pleasure :-)